# How can I check .mo file validity?

Tags: php, gettext, po, mo

I'm using PHP to make .mo files out of the database and have run into a strange problem: some keys work, some don't. I think there is some kind of a problem with the generated files. How can I check, whether a .mo file is correct?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `msgunfmt`, which is the opposite of `msgfmt`:

```
msgunfmt something.mo
```

If the `.mo` file is messed up, `msgunfmt` will complain.

Comment: This worked great. If on MacOS, and using Homebrew. You can do `brew install gettext` and then `brew link get text` and then have access to this command.

Answer (score 0):

[polib](https://bitbucket.org/izi/polib/wiki/Home) can open and read .mo files; it should not be difficult to create a small tool that iterates through the entries, allowing you to verify them.